# What are those hydroponic beads called?

Tags: hydroponic, growing-medium

What are the beads this guy is scooping out in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/3Gjd5DRyeks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That look like Hydroton, which explained above is expanded clay.

It is highly porous and holds moisture very well, and is used in a lot of Deep Water Culture/Aquaponic/Hydroponic applications.

Comment: That's a lot cheaper than the previous answer.

Comment: If you are looking for economic solutions, you might also look into expanded shale and growstones, but I've never used them personally.

Comment: It's for a hack-a-thon project, so we're shoe stringing the project.

Comment: Cool, are you guys doing anything code related? What is your objective? Is there a project page? Good luck with it

Comment: Yes, with PLCs, why do you ask?

Comment: I am (slowly) working on a pH/Nutrient controller with Raspi. Interested in similar type projects and how they're executed.

Comment: That project sounds like: FUN!!!

Comment: Cheapest, but also heaviest, is to find a pH stable gravel I.e. with no limestone

Answer (score 9):

These are called by various names but the one I am familiar with is LECA. It stands for Lightweight Expanded Clay aggregate and is made by [this company](http://www.leca.ae/).

Having seen this material used in twenty and thirty year old installations I can attest to its durability.  Lightweight?  Not so much.